# Next.js - NextAuth throws error in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

My next-auth works fine until a certain time. [image]

But then, its throwing (The red session text in the picture above)

```
GET https://yazankasa-eng.vercel.app/api/auth/session 504 [next-auth][error][client_fetch_error] 


https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error session SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
```

And it says "An unexpected error has occurred." on the screen. Is there any way I can deal with this? Thanks

Comment: _"next-auth works fine until a certain time"_ - at what point does it stop working exactly? Have you configured the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, I configured the NEXTAUTH_URL.  I really dont know why it is stop working exactly, its happening randomly